# Swift - toolbar follows tableview when scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, toolbar

In my UITableViewController, my toolbar follows my tableview when I scroll it. My code looks like this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        let toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()
        let checkButton = [UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Done, target: self, action: "checkedPress")]
        toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 46, self.view.frame.size.width, 48)
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        toolbar.setItems(checkButton, animated: true)
        toolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
    }
```

and it looks like this when I run the app:
[image]

I want the toolbar to stick to the bottom of the view, how is this achieved?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that since you're using a `UITableViewController`, with `self.view.addSubview(toolbar)`, you've added your toolbar as a subview of your `UITableViewController`'s `view`, i.e. a `UITableView`. As a subview of the `UITableView`, the toolbar will scroll along with the table.

The solution: Use a `UIView` containing a `UITableView` instead of using a `UITableViewController` if you'd like to customize your view controller. That way you can add elements to the view that aren't subviews of your tableview.

Comment: To add to this answer, you should also use constraints versus setting the frame's size directly. This way you can ensure that the toolbar is pinned to the bottom of your UIViewController's view's bottom, and then pin your tableView's bottom to the toolbar's top. Calculating frames and setting them directly is no longer the suggested approach by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

You can also embed your TableViewController in a Navigation Controller and show from the storyboard or programmatically a Toolbar. This one also standard sticks to the bottom and stays on top of the Views content and you have some functionality to hide it automatically on some conditions.

[image]

You don't have to use your Navigation controller always for navigating, sometimes its a convenient way for doing stuff Xcode makes hard to use without changing your already made Views.